# Prevent Bootstrap Tooltips from colliding with eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a situation where Tooltips may be displayed next to eachother, and may collide with eachother. I'm trying my best to keep this from happening by dynamically changing the data-placement of the Tooltips.

**What I have currently**

[image]

[image]

You can see that I've ensured a Tooltip will never occupy more than 3 spaces above, right, bottom or to the right.

I'm currently simply checking the surrounding spaces for another Desk. If there is one, I don't put a Tooltip in that direction. However you can see in the first example that doesn't always work and to work would require me to check surrounding spaces for Tooltips instead.

I am aware there may be situations where a Tooltip can neither be placed above, right, bottom or to the left and in that situation I'm okay with just placing the Tooltip in a random direction.

Is there an easier way of doing this without me keeping track of which Tooltips are in which spaces?

Comment: Tooltips are really meant to be displayed one at a time. I think you're using the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @Blazemonger What would you recommend? I really love the look and clarity of this method of identifying desks.